# New created attributes not found, after use EavSetup to create

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I use \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup to create a new attribute. Note that this is not implemented on *Install* or *Upgrade* as the function is for import the latest data from other sources.

The problem is after successfully created a attribute, assigned to the group and set. When fetching the product attributes, the new attribute is not found. Even after clearing cached, and cause the process crashes

But when access the Magento Admin, the attributes created and shown correctly, that makes the next import successful.

**Create attribute**

```
$setup = $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
$attributeValue = array(
        'group'                   => $group,
        'type'                    => 'varchar',
        'backend'                 => '',
        'frontend'                => '',
        'label'                   => $label,
        'input'                   => 'text',
        'class'                   => '',
        'source'                  => '',
        'global'                  => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'                 => true,
        'required'                => false,
        'user_defined'            => true,
        'default'                 => '',
        'searchable'              => false,
        'filterable'              => false,
        'comparable'              => false,
        'visible_on_front'        => false,
        'html_allowed_on_front'   => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => false,
        'unique'                  => false,
        'apply_to'                => ''
    );

$setup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        $attributeCode,
        $attributeValue
);
```

**Assign to group and set:**

```
// Add group
$setup->addAttributeGroup(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        $attrSetId,
        $group,
        $attributeCode,
        null
);
// Add attribute to set
$setup->addAttributeToSet(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        $attrSetId,
        $group,
        $attributeCode,
        null
);
```

**Clear cached**

```
$cache = $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface');
$types = array('config','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','full_page');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $cache->cleanType($type);
}
return;
```

I think the new attribute has not updated in the current run time environment or cached, I tried to clear the cache, but still not working.